# How do I get ReSharper to stop placing explicit access modifiers on my MSpec members?

Tags: c#, resharper, mspec

I'm using Machine.Specifications and I'm really annoyed by how VS2010/Resharper keeps trying to format my code... for example:

```
Establish context = () => the_cartoon_repository = DependencyOf<INHibernateRepository<Cartoon>>();
```

Gets turned into:

```
private Establish context = () => the_cartoon_repository = DependencyOf<INHibernateRepository<Cartoon>>();
```

As soon as I press enter. Argh! There's got to be a way around this, no?

Comment: Check the settings, probably just a setting to fix. I don't have resharper installed here, but I know the settings is quite extensive

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ReSharper options > Laguages > C# > Other > Modifiers:

Uncheck the `Use explicit private modifier`.

Comment: The ReSharper option to not use explicit private modifiers will apply Solution-wide. I'm not ok with that in my projects.

Comment: I have the same problem. It is a bad idea to turn of this helpfull setting for all projects just for the sake of the unit tests.

Comment: Additionally, see [the blog post linked from the youtrack issue](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/01/per-project-settings-or-how-to-have-different-naming-styles-for-my-test-project/) for a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The author of MSpec, Aaron Jensen, addresses a few formatting issues in [this post](http://codebetter.com/aaronjensen/2008/10/19/getting-resharper-and-vs-to-play-nice-with-mspec/). Specifically,

- explicit private modifiers
- weird lambda indentation
- field naming warnings

Comment: @Anthony, admittedly. I answered this question from my phone while being on the train ;-)

Comment: Haha, yeah, I saw "Android" in the link. Happy to help out on the mspec tag :)